# django project error ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes

Tags: python, django, linux, django-rest-framework, vps

django i have django project
when i run python manage.py runserver in my client, project runs good.
but when i push project into my vps when i run python manage.py runserver this error is showing up
why!? and how can i solve it

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/roubinaa/public_html/env/roubinaa/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/roubinaa/public_html/env/roubinaa/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/roubinaa/public_html/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/roubinaa/public_html/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 416, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/roubinaa/public_html/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/roubinaa/public_html/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 124, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "/home/roubinaa/public_html/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/apps.py", line 27, in ready
    self.module.autodiscover()
  File "/home/roubinaa/public_html/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py", line 50, in autodiscover
    autodiscover_modules("admin", register_to=site)
  File "/home/roubinaa/public_html/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 58, in autodiscover_modules
    import_module("%s.%s" % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 786, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 923, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 853, in source_to_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
```

i try to install full package of my project on the vps